# I'm unable to get top10 entries based on their count, instead I'm getting all the entries in PBI DAX

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I used below code
Total Arrests = COUNT(NYPD_Arrest_Data__Year_to_Date_[ARREST_KEY])
top 10 entries = CALCULATE(Measure_Table[Total Arrests],TOPN(10,VALUES(NYPD_Arrest_Data__Year_to_Date_[OFNS_DESC]),Measure_Table[Total Arrests], DESC))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Gkk.png)

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296271/how-to-create-table-in-stack-overflow-answers-questions)

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully tell based on your post, but why don't you add total arrests to the filters pane instead of doing this in a measure?  Then you can choose advanced filter (TOPN by your Total Arrests).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can able to do using Filter pane, but I want achieve it using DAX code.